# Display updateprogress over updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel-progressbar

What I'm trying to do is show a updateprogress over the updatepanel that I'm currently updating. Preferably I would like to show an animation of some kind of progress indicator and also disable the updatepanel under the updateprogress so that the user cannot reclick the controls that set of the update in the first place. The idea would be getting the indicator death center of the updatepanel.

I know I could just simply position absolute the updateprogress, but that would only work if the updatepanel would always be in the same place. Unfortunately this is not the case. So in this case the updateprogress should be in the middle of the updatepanel regardless of the location of it.

Does anyone have nice and clean solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

And here is the answer for those who are structling with the same problem. I downloaded the http://www.codeplex.com/FlanAjaxControls/ and there is a UpdateProgressOverlayExtender that does the trick! Thanks to Flan for greating that extender!